# StimulSoft Report Variable/ Formula with If Condition

Tags: crystal-reports, stimulsoft

I have some Crystal Formula like the following code.
I'd like to change it into  stimulsoft formula.
Could someone please help me.
Thanks in advance.

```
if {Table3.osc} = 'MAN' OR IsNull({Table3.trip}) then
   {Table3.itemtotalsellprice}
Else If UCASE({Table3.trip}) = "DISPOSAL" Then
   {Table3.itemsellprice}*{Table3.itemqty}
Else
  {@sellprice}*{Table3.itemqty}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to use next expression:

```
{ IIF (Table3.osc == "MAN" || Table3.trip == null), Table3.itemtotalsellprice, IIF(Table3.trip.ToUpper() == "DISPOSAL", Table3.itemsellprice*Table3.itemqty, @sellprice*Table3.itemqty)) }
```